# Adding external packages to Hyperledger fabric -go smartcontract

Tags: go, stripe-payments, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am trying to add an external package to my go smartcontract (for installation , I ran : go get github.com/stripe/stripe-go)  . I then imported files stripe "github.com/stripe/stripe-go" and  charge "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/charge" , in my smartcontract (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go). However, when I try to bring up my chaincode , I am getting the error :

Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error obtaining dependencies for github.com/stripe/stripe-go: : failed with error: "exit status 1"
can't load package: package github.com/stripe/stripe-go: cannot find package "github.com/stripe/stripe-go" in any of:
                /opt/go/src/github.com/stripe/stripe-go (from $GOROOT)
                /opt/gopath/src/github.com/stripe/stripe-go (from $GOPATH)

I tried adding the package through govendor  (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/Style-guides/go-style.html)  , but that also is not working .

Request you all to please hep me on this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue.
Govendor worked for me:

> error getting chaincode package bytes: Error obtaining dependencies for github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/is

```
govendor add github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/is
govendor update +v
go build
```

And result was good:

> Chaincode is installed on remote peer PEER2

UPDATE:

If you have a problem with vendor packages setup, here you go:

1. create folder vendor in project root directory with empty valid json file (vendor.json)
2. run command `govendor add +external` from root directory
3. you can also update all dependencies with update command.

Comment: Hi Munin , Thank you for your reply . It looks that I am missing out on a few basic things , Can you please tell me from which location did you run the govendor thing and did you make any changes to the go env variables after that. Any document if you followed, will be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I just created folder vendor in project root directory with empty valid json file (vendor.json).
Then ran command `govendor  add +external` from root directory and all went well.
If you need you can also update all dependencies with update command.
I didn't setup any additional go env. And build project with tags --nopksc11 because of Windows.

Comment: You both are life saver to me. Thank you very much for this question and answer.I was stuck in this problem for like two months :D. God bless you both